# Is there Visual Studio 2015 Debugging step skipping?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I installed the new version of Visual Studio Community 2015.

Opened old Visual Studio 2010 projects. They compiled okay.
Then when I needed to debug them I found out something strange.

When I try to Step Over(F10) just skips lines of code like they weren't there.[image: enter image descrihgdfhption here]

For example I start debugging in line 33, then F10 sends me right to line 43.

How is that?

And is it configurable.

Comment: the compiler probably removes the lines in between, because they have no effect.

Comment: Release build or debug build?

Comment: This is example that skips and also I cant see in debugger the variable value. Or if result is positive it jumps to line 40, skipping the init of the variable and the if statement.
Either(Release and Debug) behaves like this.

Comment: It happens to me when the code that is skipped won't compile! I had a method that referred to library compiled for .Net4.5 whereas my project referenced .Net4.0 . Changing the library reference to the .Net4.0 build fixed it. This is not an answer because I don't want VS2015 to skip anything!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is consistent with debugging optimized code.

You can verify what code was generated by going to Tools -> ILDasm, loading your executable and inspecting that function. Or, while on a breakpoint in the Debugger, Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly (or click Alt+8).

This may be a new feature in 2015, as my 2013 does not optimize that assignment/test out...

Comment: Thank you very much! Nowhere says what is going on with this step skipping. So I am glad that I asked.

Comment: Is there anywhere to turn this off?

Comment: @mituw16 - see if your "Optimize code" checkbox is checked in project's properties, Build tab.

Comment: I don't have a checkbox for "Optimize Code" in the build tab. I'm using VS2015 Professional

Comment: @mituw16 Is it .NET / C# project? What version of the Studio? What controls do you see in that Build tab?

Comment: It's an MVC6 C# project. VS2015 Professional. In the Build Tab I see checkboxes for "Produce Outputs on Build" and "Compile TypeScript on Build" along with the normal configuration (Active, Release, Debug) select boxes

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2015, this has happened to me in Release mode. After changing to Debug mode, debugger stepped thru each line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Midwesterner. This was helpful to me. I changed to Debug build and that resolved the issue for me as well.

Comment: Same here, accidentally running in beta instead of debug

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, this happened in release mode, change to debug. it will work fine