# Visual Studio 2015 Community not debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2015

If I put a break point on a line in a MVC project and then run the project.  It'll break on the line and then when I press F10 or F11, it'll skip all the rest of the code and go straight from the Controller to the View code, anyone know why.  F10/11 works in the views but not the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw this post earlier...  [Is there Visual Studio 2015 Debugging step skipping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547907/is-there-visual-studio-2015-debugging-step-skipping) but only just noticed the answer hidden in the comments rather than the answer.

@mituw16 - see if your "Optimize code" checkbox is checked in project's properties, Build tab. – Vlad Feinstein Feb 16 at 14:29